# Failure when trying to use serialize on argument from onSubmit='return function(this)'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, onsubmit

New to javascript here, so sorry if this is elementary...

So I've got a form, and I want to do some AJAX with it upon confirmation (confirm box after submit). The outermost layer of the problem is that the serialize() isn't working--it returns a blank string. Obviously, I suspect there is more under the surface as to why it isn't working…

My goal here is to have the form go to the onsubmit method (confirm_delete()), upon which some AJAX is done (when user confirms desire to delete). Either way, I don't want the form submitting and loading a new page--hence the 'return false;''s--I want the AJAX to take over.

So…this is the form:

```
<form class='delete_item' method='post' onSubmit='return confirm_delete(this)'>
   //lots of inputs here. . . .                             
   <button type='submit' class='btn-xs btn-danger remove_submit'>X</button>
</form>
```

And here's my javascript/AJAX attempt…

```
function confirm_delete(form){
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
    var data = form.serialize();
//  var x = 9;
    if (r == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(response){
               alert('hi');
               //do stuff….
            }
        });
          return false;
        } else {
           return false;
        }   
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.serialize` is a jQuery method, not a native `JavaScript` method, so you need to utilize the `jQuery` wrapper (`$()`) to use it

```
//..
function confirm_delete(form){
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
//note the $(form).serialize() vs form.serialize()
    var data = $(form).serialize(); 
//rest of your code...
```

Comment: Wow…I wish I would've posted this 2 hours ago…! Thanks!